# How to create a nested python dictionary with keys as strings?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, for-loop, nested

Summary of issue: I'm trying to create a nested Python dictionary, with keys defined by pre-defined variables and strings.  And I'm populating the dictionary from regular expressions outputs.  This mostly works.  But I'm getting an error because the nested dictionary - not the main one - doesn't like having the key set to a string, it wants an integer.  This is confusing me.  So I'd like to ask you guys how I can get a nested python dictionary with string keys.

Below I'll walk you through the steps of what I've done.  What is working, and what isn't.  Starting from the top:

```
# Regular expressions module
import re

# Read text data from a file
file = open("dt.cc", "r")
dtcc = file.read()

# Create a list of stations from regular expression matches
stations = sorted(set(re.findall(r"\n(\w+)\s", dtcc)))
```

The result is good, and is as something like this:
stations = ['AAAA','BBBB','CCCC','DDDD']

```
# Initialize a new dictionary
rows = {}

# Loop over each station in the station list, and start populating 
for station in stations:
    rows[station] = re.findall("%s\s(.+)" %station, dtcc)
```

The result is good, and is something like this:
rows['AAAA'] = ['AAAA 0.1132 0.32 P',...]

However, when I try to create a sub-dictionary with a string key:

```
for station in stations:
    rows[station] = re.findall("%s\s(.+)" %station, dtcc)
    rows[station]["dt"] = re.findall("%s\s(\S+)" %station, dtcc)
```

I get the following error.

> "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

It doesn't seem to like that I'm specifying the second dictionary key as "dt".  If I give it a number instead, it works just fine.  But then my dictionary key name is a number, which isn't very descriptive.

Any thoughts on how to get this working?

Comment: `rows[station]` points to a list, not a dictionary. That is because of this statement where you are assigning a list to the outer dictionary keys: `rows[station] = re.findall("%s\s(.+)" %station, dtcc)`. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but a start might be: `rows[station] = dict.fromkeys(re.findall("%s\s(.+)" %station, dtcc))`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that by doing

```
rows[station] = re.findall(...)
```

You are creating a dictionary with the station names as keys and the return value of `re.findall` method as values, which happen to be lists. So by calling them again by

```
rows[station]["dt"] = re.findall(...)
```

on the LHS `row[station]` is a list that is indexed by integers, which is what the TypeError is complaining about. You could do `rows[station][0]` for example, you would get the first match from the regex. You said you want a nested dictionary. You could do

```
rows[station] = dict()
rows[station]["dt"] = re.findall(...)
```

To make it a bit nicer, a data structure that you could use instead is a `defaultdict` from the `collections` module.

The defaultdict is a dictionary that accepts a default type as a type for its values. You enter the type constructor as its argument. For example `dictlist = defaultdict(list)` defines a dictionary that has as values lists! Then immediately doing `dictlist[key].append(item1)` is legal as the list is automatically created when setting the key.

In your case you could do

```
from collections import defaultdict

rows = defaultdict(dict)

for station in stations:
    rows[station]["bulk"] = re.findall("%s\s(.+)" %station, dtcc)
    rows[station]["dt"] = re.findall("%s\s(\S+)" %station, dtcc)
```

Where you have to assign the first regex result to a new key, `"bulk"` here but you can call it whatever you like. Hope this helps.